# Ошибка "Permission denied"

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите пожалуйста что делать, при загрузки таблицы c данными возникает ошибка "D:: Permission denied".
OS windows 10pro

Comment: Дать права в файловой системе, что ж ещё...

Comment: я запускал SQL Shell (psql) как админ, все права есть.

Comment: Речь не идёт о правах на SQL-сервере. Речь идёт о правах учётной записи операционной системы, от имени которой запускается сервис сервера? на файловую систему сервера.

Comment: Прошу прощение, не совсем понял ваш вопрос, я проверял права доступа в свойствах файла, все разрешения там стоят.

Comment: *все разрешения там стоят.* Кому? Но даже если на файл есть прямое назначение - а учётка туда сможет добраться по дереву каталогов?

Comment: я проверил начиная с диска D, разрешения стоят для admin/user/Система.

Comment: MySQL-служба стартует от системы? Учётка в MySQL имеет permission FILE? В настройках сервера разрешено load_file?